# How could I contact site's admins besides contact form and email?

Tags: contacts, website, registration

There is www.java-forums.org, which has problems with registration: there validation picture that should be used during registration, but no picture appear.
Also there contact form that should be used if problems like that appear, but there's the same picture thing going on.
It seems there is no email to contact them, how could I tell them about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Find contact us link for the webmaster .. you can find out in homage of the site or the footer area

Or you can simply go with www.who.is site and you can find site owner throughout this link [enter link description here](http://who.is)

Give it a try and let me know how it goes:)

Comment: On Saturday or Sunday I sent an email - nothing.

Comment: @RS can you tell me which website you are looking for

Comment: I've found already, just initially wanted to register on java-forums. Thanks.